# How to buy a Probe Bahncard without username and password?

Tags: trains, germany

I want to buy the German *[Probe Bahncard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BahnCard)*, a discount subscription programme offered by *Deutsche Bahn (DB),* the German national railway company.

**Problem:** If I click on the [buy and print button on the website](http://www.bahn.de/p/view/bahncard/ueberblick/probebahncard.shtml) (in German it is *Buchen und ausdrucken*) a popup window asks me to enter **username and password**. But which username and password do they mean? Can anybody help?

What I have tried so far:

- I registered at bahn.de and have used the [general Bahn.de account](https://fahrkarten.bahn.de/privatkunde/meinebahn/meine_bahn_portal.go?lang=de&country=DEU) data to login, but this did not work
- I left the username and password field blank or entered some arbitrary usernames and passwords, but that just redisplays the popup window
- I clicked on the cancel button (*Abbrechen*), but that lead to an error 401 page

[image]

Comment: Presumably a [general Bahn.de account](https://fahrkarten.bahn.de/privatkunde/meinebahn/meine_bahn_portal.go?lang=de&country=DEU) that can be created from [the login page](https://fahrkarten.bahn.de/privatkunde/start/start.post;jsessionid=9tLTS3ZZNNdNTLpJ7r1w8g9pZFnNsxhy9cn2t2dqJynTrpxCfVQL!357664846?shopId=9683c&click_id=1.3619207391201464&from_page=meinebahn&scope=bahnregaendern&lang=de&country=DEU). Did you try that?

Comment: No, this is not working. I tried that a few minutes ago.

Comment: Looks like a website bug to me - I'd suggest trying again in a few hours

Comment: Seems to be working now.

Comment: @erik any luck?

Comment: @Mark Mayo yes, seems to work now. But to late for me.

Comment: Voting to close as it turned out to be a website glitch.

Comment: Ok, close it. It is of no help if it isn’t an iterative bug.